# How are "first" and "second" books of the Bible pronounced?

Tags: pronunciación, números

The Bible has several books in multiple parts (e.g. 1 Corintios, 2 Pedro, 3 Juan). How are these books said out loud? For example, is 1 Pedro pronounced *Primer de Pedro*, *Primero de Pedro*, *Primera de Pedro*, *Pedro Uno*, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old Testament: All of them are "Libro de..." except for "El Cantar de los Cantares"

- Books named after someone (ex: Job) While talking about it you would say "El Libro de Job" but if you are locating a reading or a quote you could say "Job 26:7"
- Other titles depends, some of them are usually referred as "Libro de..." (éxodo, reyes...) and others just by the name (Génesis, Levítico, Deutoronomio...)

New Testament:

- The Gospels: "Evangelio según  San...", if you want to quote them it's usual " En Lucas X:X..."
- Acts is "Hechos de los Apóstoles", "Hechos" for short.
- The Epistles: "X Carta de San... a ..." for example "Primera carta de San Pablo a los Corintios" for short "Primera a los Corintios"
- Revelation: "Apocalipsis según San Juan" "Libro del Apocalipsis" for short "Apocalipsis"

Comment: So what would the "spoken" forms be for 1 Crónicas, 1 Pedro, and 1 Juan? Those don't seem to fit into any of those cases.

Comment: Primer libro de las Crónicas. Primera (segunda) carta de San Pedro, Primera (segunda, tercera) carta de San Juan. How they don't fit? Maybe in english Peter and John are not considered epistles? By the way Crónicas is called too "Libro de los Paralipómenos"

Comment: They are considered epistles, I just asked because your example was a letter "to" the Corinthians, not "from" a person like Peter and John. That does clear it up, so "books" are "primer de" and "letters" are "primera de."